# CSS to tell this kendo splitter to use 100% of browser window height?

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-splitter

What CSS is required to make this splitter use 100% of vertical space, so that it extends from the top of the browser window to the bottom of the browser window?

http://dojo.telerik.com/aHIzozUw/3

Answer (score 1):

Just add below `CSS` will resolve your issue. Try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
#vertical-tiers {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!  The CSS you suggested does give the splitter "window" full height. But do the `k-splitbar-horizontal`and `k-splitbar-draggable-horizontal` classes need to be adjusted as well?

Comment: It this answer resolve your issue and help you out. Please marked as correct. Thanks

Comment: The splitter bar does not extend the full-height of the middle tier.

Comment: You mean `main-pane` container ?

Comment: The vertical bar that separates the left and right panes of the middle tier is truncated. That bar remains the original height. It does not grow along with the panes it is separating.